# MS Access DB produces run time error 2473 inconsistently

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

An Access DB I designed produces the run time error 2473 stating "Object or class does not support the set of events". The error is produced inconsistently, which makes it very hard for me to track it down.

The debugger stops on the following line of code when it appears:

```
'Open report containing code to create TOC with list of ISINs from above
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewPreview, , strWhere
```

Even when the error occurs, this code works fine for some reports, but produces the run time error for others. After opening up the report and the underlying queries in design mode, the run time error sometimes disappears, even though I have changed absolutely nothing in the code, the forms, or even updated the underlying data.

In an attempt to get at this problem, I have **restored my DB** to an earlier version where I know the problem still existed, but **upon opening up the restored version, it no longer has a run time error either!**

**What could cause this behavior?**

UPDATE:
Full code as contained in the Form

```
Sub cmdFundSelectionReport_Click()
'Gather selected ISIN and pass it to Fund Selection Report
Dim var As Variant
Dim sFund As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lst As Access.ListBox
Dim i As Integer
Dim rptType As Integer

'Create list of isin to send to report
Set lst = Me.libFilterSelection
rptType = Me.cmbReportType

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 0 To lst.ListCount - 1
    If Not dict.Exists(lst.Column(1, i)) Then
        dict.Add lst.Column(1, i), i
    End If
Next i

Dim a As Variant
a = dict.keys

strWhere = "[ISIN] IN("
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    strWhere = strWhere & """" & a(i) & ""","
Next i
strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 1)
strWhere = strWhere & ")"

'Set dictionary back
Set dict = Nothing

Dim rptName As String
Select Case rptType
Case 2
    rptName = "rptRDRSelectionList" '2 is the RDR List
    'strWhere = strWhere & " AND Fund_Selection=2"
Case 3
    rptName = "rptAsiaSelectionList" '3 Asia
    'strWhere = strWhere & " AND Fund_Selection=3"
Case Else
    rptName = "rptFundSelectionList" '0 = Fund Selection
    'strWhere = strWhere & " AND Fund_Selection=0"
End Select

'Open Report for view
OpenReport rptName, strWhere

'Write Log
WritelogMessage Now & " | User: " & fncUserName & " | Report Created | ReportName: " & rptName

End Sub

Sub OpenReport(rptName As String, strWhere As String)

'Open report containing code to create TOC with list of ISINs from above
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewPreview, , strWhere

'Click through report so that TOC code is executed
Dim rptCurReport As Report
Set rptCurReport = Screen.ActiveReport

With rptCurReport
    Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, .Name
    .Visible = True 'switch to false once code is ok
    'Go through all pages
    SendKeys "{End}", True
    DoEvents
    Application.DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, .Name
    DoCmd.Close acReport, .Name, acSaveNo
End With

rptName = rptName & "TOC" 'Add TOC to get Table of Contents Report

''Check whether "Internal Use Only Flag" is set to true or false
'Dim bInternalUse As Boolean
'bInternalUse = Me.ckbInternalUse.Value
'Call modProcess.ChangeReportPicture("rptFundSelectionListTOC", "picInternalUse", bInternalUse)

'Open final report that includes the TOC as a subreport with same string of ISIN
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewPreview, , strWhere
SendKeys "{Home}", True
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: Could this refer to a missing reference?

Comment: I would think a missing reference would affect the process every time I run it, but as I wrote, even when the error is present, it will run one report but not another.

Comment: Is `rptname` a string variable? Without been able to see the rest of the code, I am wondering if this variable or the `strWhere` string is sometimes incorrectly produced.

Comment: Yes. These are both strings. I added the full code... my browser is currently not displaying the formatting options of SO, so the formatting is crap. sorry. will fix asap.

Comment: Can you post the results of your strWhere clause on the next runtime error? is it possible you have an odd ISIN value or your string has an odd character in the cases where it fails?

Comment: @dbmitch good idea. i'll check for that and post back the next time it occurrs.